Converting Model Saved by tfjs-react-native to Keras or Saved Model
I am having difficulties in converting a model saved by tfjs-react-native to a Keras or TF_Saved_Model format using tensorflowjs_converter. My intention is to use federated learning to train a global model in TensorFlow using models saved in a React Native environment.
In order to do this I attempted to convert the model by first converting the base64-encoded weights saved by tfjs-react-native to a binary file format using base64 in python like this:
# Read the Base64 encoded file
with open("model_weights", "r") as file:
    base64_string = file.read()

# Decode the Base64 string
decoded_bytes = base64.b64decode(base64_string)

# Write the decoded bytes to a .bin file
with open("output.bin", "wb") as bin_file:
    bin_file.write(decoded_bytes)

And then try to convert the model to a saved model with:
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tfjs_layers_model --output_format=keras_keras rn_model/model_data.json rn_model_conv, where model_data.json is saved by tfjs-react-native as specified by asyncStorageIO.
This was the error:
raise KeyError( KeyError: 'Field "weightsManifest" is missing from the JSON content.'

Is there a way to use the weights from a model saved in React Native to train a global model in tensorflow?

The error message KeyError: 'Field "weightsManifest" is missing from the JSON content.' suggests that the tensorflowjs_converter tool expects a specific structure in the JSON file produced by tfjs-react-native, but it's not finding the required weightsManifest field.To convert and use the model saved by tfjs-react-native for training in TensorFlow, you'll need to follow a structured approach.First, decode the base64-encoded model weights saved by tfjs-react-native into a binary format.

Make sure model_weights contains the base64-encoded weights exactly as saved by tfjs-react-native.Next, you need to prepare the model JSON file that tensorflowjs_converter can understand. Typically, tfjs-react-native saves the model architecture and other metadata along with weights. Ensure that your JSON file (model_data.json) contains at least the modelTopology and weightsManifest fields in the expected format.Use tensorflowjs_converter to convert the model:
